# IP Tables forwarding tun0 over gre1 (OpenVPN)

Tags: iptables, openvpn, gre

I haven't found a very descriptive thread (and sorry if there is one in existence - in my several hours of searching I've found nothing to my specific situation).

My main issue here is getting my traffic from tun0 (my OpenVPN server) over to gre1 (my GRE tunnel) and back.
If I setup a NAT rule, I can get the traffic to flow over eth0 just fine, but I just can't figure out why it won't route properly over gre1.

My default route is eth0. The other thing here is that I don't want all traffic flowing back to tun0 from gre1. I have binds for gre1 (nginx, etc) that are also setup. Just the traffic from tun0 out to gre1 and back.

The assigned IPs for the OpenVPN clients are 172.27.240.0/20.

Thanks for any help, it's very much appreciated.

~Chuck

Comment: Start by adding the output of the following to your question: ip route show; iptables -t nat -L -vn; iptables -L -vn; ip a

Comment: Here's a paste of the output of those commands. http://pastebin.com/We4VpuP2 In this case, tun0 is named "as0t0". I've replaced my public server IP and my GRE tunnel IP for privacy.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you don't have a `tun0` interface but are using a `tap` device.

Comment: The tap0 interface that is there isn't active. The interface that traffic is flowing from OpenVPN through is as0t0 which is a tun device.